# How to create VIEWs so they alter too when base table is ALTERed?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to link two tables, so when i alter base table, view will altered too? Something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE t (qty INT, price INT);

INSERT INTO t VALUES(3, 50);

CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT * FROM t;

SELECT * FROM v;
+------+-------+
| qty  | price |
+------+-------+
|    3 |    50 |
+------+-------+

ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN comm INT;

SELECT * FROM t;
+------+-------+------+
| qty  | price | comm |
+------+-------+------+
|    3 |    50 | NULL |
+------+-------+------+

SELECT * FROM v;
+------+-------+
| qty  | price |
+------+-------+
|    3 |    50 |
+------+-------+
```

Last two SELECT-s should be equal.

PS. I am aware that MySQL says:

> The view definition is “frozen” at creation time, so changes to the underlying tables afterward do not affect the view definition.

And creating trigger is also not possible, because trigger events does not include `ALTER TABLE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recreate view when you alter table as stated in [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)

> The view definition is “frozen” at
>   creation time, so changes to the
>   underlying tables afterward do not
>   affect the view definition. For
>   example, if a view is defined as
>   SELECT * on a table, new columns added
>   to the table later do not become part
>   of the view.

Either drop & recreate view or ALTER view too.

Comment: Yes, i am aware. Question is: how make it happen? As solid as possible, i mean.

Comment: @wk: I don't think there is a auto way constraint for this. you have to take care for this